# Need the macro to run ok even when the selection includes cells that are empty or have text

Tags: excel, vba

The macro when run on a selection takes a datetime shown as 20130808191057 and formats it as 19:10 IT.

The macro works great but if i were to select a range of cells which includes empty cell it would stop and get an error. how can I make it ignore empty cells and cells wth text. I would like to run it on a selected column if possible.

```
Sub TimeCreator()
    Dim r As Range, t As String
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        r.Clear
        r.Value = TimeSerial(Mid(t, 9, 2), Mid(t, 11, 2), Right(t, 2))
        r.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm  ""IT"""
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched how to check if a cell is empty? What results came up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy G states - you need to run a check if the cell is empty and skip if so.

You can do it like:

```
Sub TimeCreator()
    Dim r As Range, t As String
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value <> Empty Then 'test if the cell is blank (note, a zero length string is not blank in Excel)
            t = r.Text
            'r.Clear is unnecessary as you assign to r.Value
            r.Value = TimeSerial(Mid(t, 9, 2), Mid(t, 11, 2), Right(t, 2))
            r.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm  ""IT"""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

However, it would be better to only run the macro on cells that have values in the first place, which you can do using Range.SpecialCells(), like:

```
Sub TimeCreator()
    Dim r As Range, rangeToRunOn As Range, t As String
    Set rangeToRunOn = Selection.SpecialCells( _
                           xlCellTypeConstants, _
                           xlTextValues OR xlNumbers)
    If Not rangeToRunOn is Nothing Then
        For Each r In rangeToRunOn
            t = r.Text
            'r.Clear is unnecessary as you assign to r.Value
            r.Value = TimeSerial(Mid(t, 9, 2), Mid(t, 11, 2), Right(t, 2))
            r.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm  ""IT"""
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```